# SQL Server replication: Need to remove articles from the publication

Tags: sql-server, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I am replicating the data from the Database1 on Server1 to respectively, Database2 on Server2.

Now, the requirement is to remove certain tables form being replicated - so I will remove them from the Publication.
I have many articles, so am doing it using script and cursor .. but for simplicity, I will use example of one:

So, I am following this routine, but have a question:
**Questions are:**  Is there anywhere in the below, before or after where I need to

- Stop / start snapshot agent?
- Stop / start log reader agent?
- Stop / start distribution agent?

If I do have to start / stop respective agent jobs, do I do it for every article or I can do it before (stop) and after (start) the cursor loop where each article is individually dropped?

The routine followed is

```
USE Database 1
 SELECT @publicationName = name
 FROM dbo.syspublications sp


-- Change the allow_anonymous property of the publication to FALSE
   EXEC sp_changepublication
    @publication = @publicationName,
    @property = N'allow_anonymous',
    @value = 'FALSE'

    -- Next, disable Change immediate_sync
     EXEC sp_changepublication
     @publication = @publicationName,
     @property = N'immediate_sync',
     @value = 'FALSE'
```

Assuming, the following is used in the cursor-loop, and there is a variable for @articleName

```
SELECT articleName 
FROM (
    SELECT sp.pubid, sp.name as 'publicationName', sp.description, sa.artid, 
  sa.name as 'articleName', sa.dest_table, sa.schema_option
    FROM dbo.syspublications sp
    INNER JOIN dbo.sysarticles sa
    ON sp.pubid=sa.pubid
) arts
WHERE articleName = '<TheArticleName>' --In reality it will be 'like '%%'

    -- Must drop subscription first
    EXEC sp_dropsubscription 
        @publication = @publicationName, 
        @article = @articleName,-- obtained from above
        @subscriber = 'Server 2'

    -- Drop the transactional article.
    EXEC sp_droparticle 
      @publication = @publicationName, 
      @article = @articleName,
      @force_invalidate_snapshot = 1;

-- Next, Enable Change immediate_sync
EXEC sp_changepublication
@publication = @publicationName,
@property = N'immediate_sync',
@value = 'TRUE'

-- Change the allow_anonymous property of the publication to TRUE
EXEC sp_changepublication
@publication = @publicationName,
@property = N'allow_anonymous',
@value = 'TRUE'
```

Comment: I haven't followed this particular flow before.  Is there a particular reason why you are dropping the subscription?  Because you are dropping the subscription, it wouldn't make any sense to run the snapshot after removing each article.  Also, in my experience I don't need to run a snapshot after removing an article.  But if you remove the subscription and then add it again, you will need to run the snapshot, but only at the end.  Do you have other requirements?  Is it ok for the database2 to be out of date while this runs quickly?  What version of SQL Server are you using?